# Repeating another text multiple times using commands

Tags: macros

I have one command named `\commandone`, which outputs

> test.

I created it using `\newcommand\commandone{test}`

I want to have a second command `\commandtwo{}`, which takes an integer input and call the first command `\commandone` repeatedly according to the input integer. So if `\commandtwo{3}`, the output will become "

> testtesttest

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\cmd}{test}
% to provide your syntax
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% \repeat already defined
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}{\cmd}

\Repeat{6}{\cmd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it change if the document class is article? And is it possible to have just "\Repeat{6}"

Answer (score 1):

Look at David Kastrup's `\replicate`-macros:

http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl3.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\replicate[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>0 #2%
    \expandafter\replicate\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1}{#2}%
  \fi
}%
\newcommand\commandone{test}
\newcommand\commandtwo[1]{\replicate{#1}{\commandone}}

\begin{document}

\commandone

\commandtwo{3}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a variant where you in any case get the result after having `\replicate`/`\commandtwo` hit by two `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\UDfirstoftwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\UDsecondoftwo[2]{#2}

\newcommand\replicate[2]{%
  \romannumeral0\replicateb{#1}{#2}{}%
}%

\newcommand\replicateb[3]{%
  \ifnum#1>0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\replicateb\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1}{#2}{#3#2}}%
  { #3}%
}%
\newcommand\commandone{test}
\newcommand\commandtwo[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\replicate{#1}{\commandone}%
}

\begin{document}

\commandone

\commandtwo{3}%

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\replicate{4}{\commandone}}

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testb
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\commandtwo{5}}

\texttt{\meaning\testb}


\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a variant which does without ϵ-TeX-extensions/without `\numexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\UDfirstoftwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\UDsecondoftwo[2]{#2}

\newcommand\replicate[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\replicateA
                \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\replicateA[2]{\replicateB{#2}{}#1\relax}
\newcommand\replicateB[3]{%
  \if#3m\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
  {\replicateB{#1}{#2#1}}{ #2}%
}%


\newcommand\commandone{test}
\newcommand\commandtwo[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\replicate{#1}{\commandone}%
}

\begin{document}

\commandone

\commandtwo{3}%

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\replicate{4}{\commandone}}

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testb
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\commandtwo{5}}

\texttt{\meaning\testb}


\end{document}
```

[image]